# Deploying app with stripe integration in apple store

Tags: ios, testing, app-store, stripe-payments

I have an iPhone app with stripe payment integration. We have done testing using test key and card numbers. Now we are ready to deploy app using prod key in app store. Is there any stripe test account and card number available in prod environment?  or Do I have to use real bank account and credit card in prod environment?

Payment is main functionality in our app so apple app reviewer needs cards / account information while reviewing the app. What accounts should I provide to apple in notes while deploying app?

How do you guys handle payment integration app deployment in apple store?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

There are no test numbers that are usable in live mode, as that would be a huge vulnerability (anyone who knows you're using Stripe to process your payments could use those numbers).

Rather than embedding the publishable key directly within your app's code, you should instead retrieve the key dynamically at runtime, from your own backend server. This has several advantages:

- you can create a "debug mode" in your app and instruct your backend server to return the test key rather than the live key
- if you ever need to replace the keys, you will not have to update the app itself and force your customers to update

Comment: Thank you Ywain. One question - is it safe to send keys in api response? Do you recommend any security options to block unauthorized access to keys?